# Azure Web App Configuration not able to Edit/Delete

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

When I was trying to Edit my Web App through Configuration I see those options are disabled !Not sure what happened !

[image: No]

Comment: I am wondering if you have permissions to change application settings? That could be the reason these are disabled.

Comment: I'm the owner of the subscription , also I was managing these web app (editing configuration) more often even last week also It worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, Lesson learned, I found what is the cause for this at last.

Actually I was performing some slot swap along with the Preview feature. I started the swap and left before complete it (totally forget)

Due to this, my configurations were gone to read-only mode. Once I completed the swap I can now able to edit the configurations.

[image]